# Expand divs in column layout to match original height of parent

Tags: css, flexbox

As the title specifies: I have a number of divs in a column layout, and I would like them to expand to match the original height of the parent.

The parent doesn't have a fixed height, as it is part of a flex-based page layout.

Is this possible? In the attached example, I would like both `.child` divs to be equal in height, and the same height as the original height of the parent.

I can believe that it is impossible based on the way that CSS works.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  flex: 1;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may imbricate flex boxes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container ,.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.parent, .child {
  flex: 1;
  min-height:auto;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

For the other part of the question : *the same height as the original height of the parent.* sibblings or parent of .container looks like missing to visualize  how height is applied or comes from.

Could be something alike:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container,
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

---

**edit** , from comment

For chrome, A bit of js can used to set a usable min-height value for that browser (and others).

```js
let MyParent  = document.querySelector('.parent');
let MyParentH = MyParent.offsetHeight;
MyParent.style.setProperty("--MyHeight", MyParentH +"px");
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container,
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100%;/* where var css is not supported */
   min-height:var(--MyHeight, 100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! I was missing the `overflow: auto` property. Once that is added, the child height of 100% works perfectly :-)

Comment: on further testing, this doesn't work. It worked in FireFox, but not in Chrome. I think what I'm trying to do is probably not possible. Sorry!

Comment: @Joaquimd'Souza okay, can we see the css you used that is not working in Chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

PS: Update my answer with comment advice

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.parent {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

give `100%` of the parents width to its children.

```
.parent {
  display: 'flex';
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}
```